# How to solve this error Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in createProduct blade file?

Tags: php, laravel

I have to show brand name in create product form select list where brand name come from brand model but when I viewing create product form this error is occurred

Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\MobileShop\resources\views\admin\product\createProduct.blade.php

My brand Model is:

```
class brand extends Model
 {

  protected $connection = 'mysql';

  protected $primaryKey = 'id';

  protected $fillable = ['brandName'];

  public $timestamps = false;

  public function product(){

 return $this->hasMany('App\Product');

     }

   protected $table = 'brands';
```

}

My product Model is

```
class Product extends Model

  {
  protected $connection = 'mysql';

  protected $table = 'products';

  protected $primaryKey = 'id';

  public $timestamps = false;

  protected $fillable = 
       ['productName','brand_id','description','price','image'];


   public function brand(){

        $this->belongsTo('App/brand');
   }
 }
```

ProductController create method

```
enter  public function create()
  {
    $product = brand::pluck('brandName','id');

    return view('admin.product.createProduct',compact('product'));
  }
```

And my createProduct blade view file is

```
   <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{url('/product')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                  {{csrf_field()}}

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Product Name :</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required autofocus>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Brand:</label>

                       <div class="col-md-6">

                            <select name="cars" class="form-control" >
                             @foreach($product as $item)
                               <option value="{{$item->id}}">  #-->this line error occure#
                                   {{$item->brandName}}
                               </option>
                             @endforeach
                           </select>

                       </div>
                   </div>

                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="description" class="col-md-4 control-label">Description :</label>

                       <div class="col-md-6">
                           <textarea name="description" id="description" class="form-control" ></textarea>

                       </div>
                   </div>

                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="price" class="col-md-4 control-label">Price :</label>

                       <div class="col-md-6">
                           <input id="price" type="text" class="form-control" name="price" required autofocus>

                       </div>
                   </div>
```

Comment: $item is in which table?

Comment: try `$item['id']` instead `$item->id`

Comment: change this $this->belongsTo('App/brand'); to $this->belongsTo('App\brand'); you are using wrong '/' in your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this 
{{Form::select('cars', $product, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
Instead of 
<select name="cars" class="form-control" >
   @foreach($product as $item)
      <option value="{{$item->id}}">  #-->this line error occure#
      {{$item->brandName}}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>

Otherwise get all data instead of pluck
$product = brand::all();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Passing second argument to `pluck` means that you have a `key => value` **array** (`brandName` will be value, `id` will be key).

So `$product = brand::pluck('brandName','id');` will give you an array like:

```
['id1' => 'brandName1', 'id2' => 'brandName2']
```

So, in your template you should iterate this way:

```
@foreach($product as $id => $name) 
{{ $id }} - {{ $name }}
@endforeach
```